# How to access child node using parent key ?? in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have 2 database node one is friends and other User. In User node all the user which are using my app are registered but in friend node those  keys are available which are friends. In friends node One key (parent key ) can have multiple child key (also present in User node). Now I want to access data of User node Using Friend child child (2times) key.

[image]

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: yeah i solved it ............

Comment: How did you solve it? Kindly share.

Comment: @GordonAndroidJavalist this is the following code :----------

Comment: FriendReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(Online_user_id);
        FriendReference.keepSynced(true);
        DatabaseReference get_type_ref=FriendReference.child("Location").getRef();
        get_type_ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
               //access lat long using datasnapshot
                );
 
            }

Comment: i hope this code work for you .........this not full code..

Comment: Let me try it. Thanks very much.