# How to access Firebase key node all children when parent node is also a key in hierarchy

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I trying to access UserInfo, I've stored in Firebase Realtime Database with Database Reference like this
Notification -> SenderUserId -> ReceiverUserId.

Please Check the image I want to access all children of ReceiverId Node
As I am new the picture won't appear there is a link only:
[Link to screenshot so that you guys can understand clearly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbb6G.png)

I try some answer but it didn't work for me.
[1) Link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616054/how-to-access-child-node-using-parent-key-in-firebase-android)

[2)Link to second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117178/how-to-get-children-keys-from-firebase-without-downloading-their-children)

[3)Link to 3rd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51190160/get-parent-name-using-child-key-in-firebase-android)

How I am storing this data:

```
private void AllNotificationInfo()
    {
        Calendar calForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
        saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calForDate.getTime());


        Calendar calForTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calForTime.getTime());

        UsersRef.child(SenderUserId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             if (dataSnapshot.exists())
             {
                 String  userprofileImage = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                 String fullname = dataSnapshot.child("Full_Name").getValue().toString();

                 HashMap postsMap = new HashMap( );

                 postsMap.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
                 postsMap.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
                 postsMap.put("profileimage", userprofileImage);
                 postsMap.put("fullname", fullname);

                 NotificationRef.child(SenderUserId).child(ReceiverUserId).updateChildren(postsMap)
                         .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                             @Override
                             public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                                 if (task.isSuccessful()){

                                     Toast.makeText(PersonProfileActivity.this, "Friend Request Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                     Toast.makeText(PersonProfileActivity.this, "Error! "+message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                 }
                             }
                         });
             }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

The data is stored properly. No issue but I can't retrieve my data

and I am storing data in one activity and retrieving in another activity.

This is how I tried to retrieve the Info:

```
public class NotificationsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar NotificationToolbar;

    private RecyclerView RnotificationList;
    private DatabaseReference NotificationRef, UsersRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String notification_sender_id,CurrentUserId;
    List<String> NKeyList;
    List<NotificationModel> NotificationList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notifications);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        CurrentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        NotificationToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.notification_toolbar_layout);
        setSupportActionBar(NotificationToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Notifications");

        RnotificationList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.notification_list);

        RnotificationList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        RnotificationList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        NotificationRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notifications");

        NKeyList = new ArrayList<>();
        NotificationList = new ArrayList<>();

        NotificationRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        NKeyList.add(dataSnapshot1.getKey());
// Here I am getting the senderKey and converting into a string, I tried one only at index 0 for testing.
//then I am passing the key to a method where I am using this key for DatabaseReference.
                        String key = NKeyList.get(0);
                        GettingRequestSenderInfo(key);
                }

            }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });





    }

    private void GettingRequestSenderInfo(final String key) {

        DatabaseReference ReqSenderRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notifications")
                .child(key).child(CurrentUserId);


 //Here above "key" is SenderUserId and CurrentuserId is ReceiverUserId
        ReqSenderRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        NotificationModel model = dataSnapshot1.getValue(NotificationModel.class);
                        NotificationList.add(model);
                    }

                    NotificationAdapter notificationAdapter1 = new NotificationAdapter(NotificationsActivity.this, NotificationList, NKeyList);
                    RnotificationList.setAdapter(notificationAdapter1);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

But I am getting NotificationList empty. there is no value...
I am using RecyclerView, there is one Model Class and Adapter Class if necessary I'll include both classes.But I am getting Null NotificationList All I want to access the data showed in the image above please check.

Answer (score 0):

**I think the saved node must be like this `Notfications/ReceiverID/SenderID`:**

```
NotificationRef.child(ReceiverUserId).child(SenderUserId).updateChildren(postsMap)
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

..............
..............
```

**Now in the `NotificationsActivity`:**

**make sure the ref is correctly read:**

```
NotificationRef =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notifications").child(CurrentUserId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it gives NullPointerException, as we can see in the screenshot there is another node "ReceiverUserId" I've to access that also to go one step deeper for accessing data, I don't know how to access that key(ReceiverUserId) in NotificationActivity.